# updating view from gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access, gridview

My query is

```
SELECT  
    deldate,
    transno,
    matno,
    MAT_NAME,
    rawpkgno,
    MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [CURRDATE],
    MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [previous_day],
    MAX(SWITCH(deldate=? ,ORDCASES )) AS [Last_date]
FROM 
    invorder
WHERE
    invorder.strno =54009
    OR [invorder.deldate] IS NULL
GROUP BY
    matno,
    MAT_NAME,
    rawpkgno,
    transno,
    deldate
```

I want to edit this from gridview. As this is view I cannot edit it from gridview. But is their any way through which `previous_day`, `Last_date` columns can be constant and I can only make changes to `CURRDATE` column. Kindly help me.

Comment: so you want to say you want to make the only currDate as editable in gridview not prev_day and last_date..?? right??

Comment: yes I should be able to edit CURRDATE column,And just for verification I need previous_day, Last_date to be visible in the table

Comment: what u can do just make the grid noneditable and add the row_added event on grid and there make the particular column editable.

Comment: I dint write any code for this I just configured it with some sql queries.Can I do what you have told just by configuring.And also doing this will effect database table?

Comment: u can make all the fields in grid - **Editable or non-editable** using configuration wizard.. but to make a single field **Editable or non-editable** u have to code little bit..

Comment: ok Thank you.If possible can you please help me with code?

Comment: Sure wait i will send u the sample

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to bind the row_added event on grid and there make the all the cell read only except u want editable.. check the below code..

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.RowsAdded += new DataGridViewRowsAddedEventHandler(dataGridView1_RowsAdded);  
    }

    void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell item in dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells)
        {
            // here i used the 5 because i want to make the 5th index cell as editable.
            if (item.ColumnIndex == 5)
            {
                continue;
            }
            item.ReadOnly = true;
        }            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bind_your_data_source_here;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

you can find the sample from here.. 
[Download](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bxxluya0NKB2ZEk4UHd6Q21aNFE)